If all nodes of a private Ethereum network built with Geth+Prysm go down, how to restore the network?
I plan to use Geth+Prysm to build an Ethereum private blockchain as L1, and use Optimism as L2 to learn and understand Ethereum Rollup.
There is a tricky problem with the L1 network.
As long as all nodes of L1 are shut down, the L1 network cannot be restored, and L2 cannot be restored. If it runs for a long time, all blockchain data will be lost, and the L1 and L2 networks have to be reset. I don’t want this.

Stop all L1 el clients, and restart them after a few minutes. The l1 network can still recover and continue to produce blocks
Stop all L1 cl clients. Even if all clients are restarted immediately, the l1 network cannot continue to produce blocks, and it cannot be recovered even after a long time
Many people have encountered the same problem. see Issues · OffchainLabs/eth-pos-devnet
Tracking the prysm program logic, I found that it is mainly stuck at this positionprysm/beacon-chain/p2p/peers/status.go at develop · prysmaticlabs/prysm. It assumes that the head slot of the peer is always larger than its own, but when all nodes are shut down, everyone’s head slot is the same, so it is deadlocked.
I don’t know if this logic is intentional or a bug? How can I restore the L1 network without losing data? Any tips will be appreciated.

Problem reproduction:

clone this repo 0xWilliamWang/geth-prysm-optimism-rollup-dmeo: This repository plans to use Geth+Prysm to build Ethereum private blockchain as L1, and ethereum-optimism/optimism: Optimism is Ethereum, scaled. as L2 to learn and understand Ethereum Rollup
start l1 networking bash helper.sh resetL1
source alias.sh
dcl1 down -v
dcl1 up -d
dcl1 logs ...

